# JQuery - How to pass active class between desktop and mobile menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab menu which shows/hides blog-posts based by category. On the mobile version of my application, I have a select dropdown instead of the tab-menu. My issue is, that when I hit a tab, let's say "nature", this tab gets the "active" class - now when I switch to the mobile version, the "nature" tab is of course not "active" - how can I solve this?

Here is my JS-code:

The tab menu:

```
var $btns = $(".tab").on("click", function(e) {
    let clickedTab = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-tab-id");
    if (clickedTab == "all") {
        $(".blog-posts > div").fadeIn(450);
    } else {
        var $el = $("." + clickedTab).fadeIn(450);
        $(".blog-posts > div")
            .not($el)
            .hide();
    }
    $btns.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

And the Select dropdown:

```
$(".blog-tab-select").change(function() {
    var selectedCategory = $(this).val();
    if (selectedCategory == "all") {
        $(".blog-posts > div").fadeIn(450);
    } else {
        $(".blog-posts .card").removeClass("active");
        var $el = $("." + selectedCategory).fadeIn(450);
        $(".blog-posts > div")
            .not($el)
            .hide();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is what my HTMl looks like:

```
<div class="blog-tabs d-none d-md-block">
  <ul>
    <li data-tab-id="all" class="tab all active">All</li>
    @foreach ($blog_categories as $category)
    <li data-tab-id="{{ strtolower($category->name) }}" class="tab {{ strtolower($category->name) }}">{{ $category->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="mobile-select d-md-none">
 <select class="custom-select blog-tab-select w-50 float-right" id="blogTabSelect" name="blogTabSelect">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    @foreach ($blog_categories as $category)
    <option data-tab-id="{{ strtolower($category->name) }}" value="{{ strtolower($category->name) }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

Do I need some kind of "state" or "eventHandler"? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any HTML, the simplest (yet not the best ofc) would be to not duplicate your logic, but instead to trigger the `<select>`'s `'change'` event - on tabs click:

```js
const $sel = $('#blogTabSelect');
const $tab = $('[data-tab]');
const $cat = $('[data-cat]');

// Select does all the job

$sel.on("change", function(e) {

  const val = this.value;
  const $tabTarget = $(`[data-tab="${val}"]`);
  const $catTarget = $(`[data-cat="${val}"]`);

  $tab.not($tabTarget).removeClass('active');
  $cat.not($catTarget).removeClass('active');
  
  if(val === 'all') {
     $cat.addClass('active');
  } else {
     $catTarget.addClass('active');
  }
  
  $tabTarget.addClass('active');
});

// LI just triggers SELECT's value and change event

$tab.on('click', function() {
  $sel.val($(this).data('tab')).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
[data-tab] {
  background: transparent;
}
[data-tab].active {
  background: #0bf;
}

[data-cat] {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
[data-cat].active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-tabs d-none d-md-block">
  <ul>
    <li data-tab="all" class="active">All</li>
    <li data-tab="cat">cat</li>
    <li data-tab="dog">dog</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="mobile-select d-md-none">
 <select id="blogTabSelect" class="custom-select blog-tab-select w-50 float-right">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class="blog-posts">
  <div data-cat="cat" class="active">cat 1...</div>
  <div data-cat="dog" class="active">dog...</div>
  <div data-cat="cat" class="active">cat 2...</div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ST80 let me see the HTML

Comment: @ST80 edited and minified the code to the essentials

Comment: Ok nice, even though this does not work when I change the select the list-items does not get updated, I will still accept this answer since I get the idea :-)

Comment: @ST80 Sorry had to run before improving. Edited now.

Comment: Vey nice:-) Thanks alot!